# How to use textsum?

Tags: tensorflow, textsum

I've been following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum) link to use textsum. I've trained the model using the command provided. But I don't see any folder 'train' in 'textsum/log_root/' directory. Since training is made on a sample file, will the model be able to work on real time test data? If not, how can I make training data and train the model? And most importantly how can I test / use the model to see the result summarization?

Answer (score 2):

I honestly can't answer why you would not see a train folder in the log_root directory if you have passed all your parameters correctly. One other thing to note is to make sure you wait long enough.  So when you execute your training run using Textsum, are you seeing any verbose logs stating there is some error such as no file list or something.  If so then your path being passed to one of the params is probably off.  It is relative to the path you are calling it from as well, so you need to make sure you are at the root path where your workspace file is.

Another thing, are you using the CPU or GPU?  If you are using the CPU...it takes a while for the model to get to the point where it is even able to write out the data.  Now if you are using the GPU then this is much faster, but you need to wait until you see the "average_loss" logs start printing to your screen.  Once you notice those, then there is  good chance you will see your "train" folder with data.

As for the "real-time" test data, I am still lookin into this myself and now that I have my current data being trained in the model, I am going to be starting on that as well. The direction, I understand so far, is that once you have trained your model and have your pickle file or whatever ti is, you can then "serve" it using the info here: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/

At that point your model is trained, and you can query against it and feed in new response so over time your model gets smarter.  Again I have not proven this yet with an example but it is the approach I am going to be starting on here soon.

With regards to "testing the model", you pretty much can follow the instructions provided on the textsum git, re-generating the vocab file, and then training.  Then after you get your average loss to a small enough fraction you can then run decode against the data. Then in your log_root decode folder you will see the headlines generated and their associated reference files (what the actual headline was).  Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Hello xtreeme, I trained my model over 1million records but it is not generating decoded summary with that of reference file.

Comment: Hey @Wazzzy...the quality is very much based on the cleanliness of the data you used for training.  Since this is an abstractive model, you will also not get an exact match as the model is literally generating something on its own based on the data that it was trained on which is why you need such a large dataset.  That said, the results should be close.  If they are not then you might want to look at the data you fed in and try to clean it up. You can easily tell how good your data is by looking at the vocab file and seeing what is in there.