# textsum decode giving summaries of other articles as result

Tags: tensorflow, textsum

I training the model using the given toy data set. And to see the result real quick, I tried to test with just one article from toy dataset. When I tested with one articles, The decoder is giving the summary of other article as a result (other article I've use in training) which is completely irrelevant to what I tested with.

Eg: My test articles is `the sri lankan government ...`

and Summary is
`sri lanka closes schools as war escalates`

But the decoder gave this
`output=outdrink germans [UNK] in stakes`.

When I tried with multiple articles for testing, The decoder is giving summaries of other articles as a result. Any one had similar issue ? Any thing I'm missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: can you please answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206413/how-to-use-textsum. I'm not able to understand how to train and test textsum model

Comment: Please refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209527/textsum-incorrect-decode-results-compared-to-ref-file