# Textsum model -Decode result is wrong

Tags: textsum

Does anyone test the textsum code to get the perfect result?

Two days ago to see the message xtr33me made " #Textsum# - Incorrect decode results compared to ref file", I now test the situation and this is the same, I use the Chinese corpus, training to running_avg_loss = 0.00001 ,but I decoded the result is wrong,What is the reason?

If anyone can provide any help or direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

[decode1480036683.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wivkPfbcbWMHgxZWpWMVNxM2M)

[ref1480036683.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wivkPfbcbWVVlQZ2dpWkw3bkU)

Answer (score 0):

check out my latest response here: [Textsum - Incorrect decode results compared to ref file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209527/textsum-incorrect-decode-results-compared-to-ref-file)

Essentially it all came down to getting more clean data, a little over 1.3million to be exact. Check out the post above should you wish for more of a detailed answer.